# Tap tab bar to Scroll to top of UITableViewController not always working

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to implement code that makes it so when I tap the tab bar item that is already selected, my tableview will scroll to the first row. I got this functionality to work most of the time by looking at other stack overflow answers; however, I noticed a weird behavior. For some reason if I never deselect the tab in the first place, the code does not work.

For example, when I first load up the app, tab 0 is selected. If I scroll down and tap tab 0 again, it does not scroll to the top. However, if I select tab 1 and then tab 0, then proceed to scroll down and press tab 0 again, it scrolls up. Why is my code not working when the tab is selected for the first time?

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
  if viewController is UINavigationController {
    if navigationController == viewController {
      let topIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
      tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(topIndexPath, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know everything about your current implementation but you can check the equality of currently selected view controller and the view controller that will be selected next by overriding the methods of `UITabBarControllerDelegate` responsible for tab selection.

Here is the partial solution;

```
@interface AppDelegate () <UITabBarControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) UIViewController *previousViewController;

@end


@implementation AppDelegate 

 - (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
{
    self.previousViewController = tabBarController.selectedViewController;
    return YES;
}

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (self.previousViewController == viewController) {
        [viewController.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
    }
}

@end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is previousViewController a property that you defined in your UITableView?

Comment: UIViewController doesn't have a tableView property. You can either try to figure out the class of viewController via isKindOfClass and cast it, or post a notification with NSNotificationCenter.

Comment: This solution works only if the Toolbar placement = "Top", it not works on "Bottom" placement